# How to Convert UNIX epoch time to Date and time in ios swift

Tags: swift, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert the UNIX epoc time to datetime format using the below code

```
var epocTime = NSTimeInterval(1429162809359)

let myDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: epocTime)
println("Converted Time \(myDate)")
```

the actual result is (Thu, 16 Apr 2015 05:40:09 GMT) but am getting something like (47258-05-14 05:15:59 +0000) Can anyone please tel me how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong value returned after formatting timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591351/wrong-value-returned-after-formatting-timestamp)

Comment: Linked question has more (slightly) detail (a reason why someone would expect this to work, the link to the other website that would convert it right, etc)., and it isn't negatively voted, it's upvoted.  So two indicators that the question is better.  And the accepted answer there is significantly better (a little biased, but I think so)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2 or later**

You need to convert it from milliseconds dividing it by 1000:

```
let epochTime = TimeInterval(1429162809359) / 1000
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: epochTime)   // "Apr 16, 2015, 2:40 AM"

print("Converted Time \(date)")         // "Converted Time 2015-04-16 05:40:09 +0000\n"
```

Comment: You are dropping the milliseconds for no good reason whatsoever.

Comment: @gnasher729 This is not dropping the milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you so much Leo... you saved my time

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5

I am dealing with a date in a JSON api which is defined as an Int and an example of the timestamp is 1587288545760 (UTC)

The only way I could display that value as a Date in a way that made any sense was to truncate the last 3 digits and convert THAT resultant date to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

This was the function I created to achieve that.

```
func convertDate(dateValue: Int) -> String {
    let truncatedTime = Int(dateValue / 1000)
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(truncatedTime))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

It works for me and I end up with a date that looks like this:

> "2020-04-19T09:29:05.000Z"

..and it reflects the fact that the original time stamp is exactly that date.

Hope that helps anyone having the same issue.

Comment: You should not scape the Z. This would work because you are also setting the timezone to UTC but if you were parsing a date string with a timezone other than UTC it would fail.

Comment: Btw you should divide by 1000 after converting the integer to Double. The string result of this method will never preserve the milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your time information is "milliseconds since 1970". Should have been straightforward to figure out: We are about 46 years after 1970, but your date is about 45,000 after 1970.

NSTimeInterval is based on SECONDS.

Convert your number to double and divide by 1000.0.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following extension on Double

```
 extension Double {
    func getDateStringFromUnixTime(dateFormat:String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self/1000))
    }
}
```