# Wrong value returned after formatting timestamp

Tags: swift, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to format a timestamp but the wrong value is returned.

```
let timestampDouble: Double = 1455970380471
let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestampDouble)
let formattedTimestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(timestamp, dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
```

formattedTimestamp returns `Jun 22, 48115, 8:49 AM` instead of the correct timestamp of `Feb 20, 2016, 11:13 PM` (from [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com)).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29670788/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the wrong value.

I reversed the process, starting with the date string you want, and ran it through this code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Feb 20, 2016, 11:13 PM")
let timeInterval = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
```

In a Swift playground, `timeInterval` has a value of `1456031580` which is three *digits* shorter than the value you're using.

When I go back to your original code and use this new value:

```
let timestampDouble: Double = 1456031580
let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestampDouble)
let formattedTimestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(timestamp, dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
```

We get the expected value: `"Feb 20, 2016, 11:13 PM"`.

Of course, note that the *exact* time interval you get (the `1456031580` number) from the first snippet and the *exact* string you get out for *that* particular number will depend on your time zone.

---

[image]

Once you linked to [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/), I pasted your original value in here and indeed got the correct value of February something-ish.  But it's important to note the bolded text.

> **Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:**

The website sees the number would give you a date 46,000 years in the future and *guesses* that you've actually given it milliseconds, so it makes a calculation based on that assumption.

`NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSince1970` constructor takes an argument of type `NSTimeInterval`, which is always a measure of *seconds*, not milliseconds.  You need to divide your original value by 1000 to get the number of seconds, or write an `NSDate` constructor which expects to be initialized with the number of milliseconds since 1970 rather than the number of seconds, as the initializer you used expects.

Answer (score 3):

You have to divide your timestampDouble by 1000 since the NSTimeInterval is in seconds and you are giving it in milliseconds.