# Creating Date object from timestamp in Swift

Tags: swift, date

I'm trying to create a date object from timestamp but the results are not expected ones.

```
var date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 1670841300000)
var date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1670841300000)
```

My expected result for `1670841300000` is **12.12.2022 10:35 AM** according to [epochconverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)
[image]

But actual results are showing something else.

[image]

Comment: It's possible that the system time zone is been applied to the output - your first screen shoot is in GMT, maybe consider using a `DateFormatter` with it's TZ set to GMT

Comment: The `Date` functions expect values in seconds, not milliseconds. Divide by 1000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert UNIX epoch time to Date and time in ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670585/how-to-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date-and-time-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @HangarRash, thanks a lot. It does. But hour and mins are still wrong.

Comment: It's showing 5:05pm but my expected is 10:35 AM, May be because of timezone

Comment: Actually, this answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648284/using-dateformatter-on-a-unix-timestamp

Comment: If this has been resolved then either post an answer yourself or remove the question or should we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, plz make it duplicate